# CSS/Ruby on Rails - break list into three separate equal width columns

Tags: css, html-lists

What's the best way to achieve something like this in a Ruby on Rails view with CSS:

**This is what I have now:**

List Item 1 - is not too long    [image] [image]
List Item 2 - very,very long and I don't want the "column" to be this large; I want it to wrap    [image] [image]
List Item 3 - hello     [image] [image]

**This is what I want:** 
[image]

The List Items come from a Solution class; the thumbs up/down are votes that come from a Solution_votes class.

Ideally, I would use a table with 3 columns, however, I am also using Axaj and JQuery to update and want to use an unordered list (to easily update using  $('#items_list').prepend(new_item);).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<ul class="entries">
  <li>
    <span class="title">List Item 1 - is not too long</span>
    <a class="thumb down">0 Votes Down</a>
    <a class="thumb up">0 Votes Up</a><!-- float:right will place this to the left -->
  </li>
  ...
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul.entries { list-style: none; }
ul.entries li {
  margin: 10px 0;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: 600px;
}
ul.entries .title {
  float: left;
  width: 380px;
}
ul.entries .thumb {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 90px;
  /* todo: color, background + padding-left declarations for thumb icons */
}
```

Comment: One caveat that I just noticed.  Even though the code shows the thumbs up icon first and then the thumbs down, the display is exactly the opposite (it's showing thumbs down first).  Any ideas why?  I need to have them in reverse order (like they are listed in the code).

Comment: OK - worked around it by listing them in reverse order in the HTML.